# How can I detect which process in Windows modified/deleted a specific file using C++ honeypot?

Tags: c++, process, honeypot

I need to detect, using C++, which process in the system (Windows) modified or deleted a specific file. I created a 'bait' file to simulate a honeypot for testing ransomware.

I would like to identify and return the exact process responsible for this modification or deletion.

I have already tried using ReadDirectoryChangesW, but it doesn't return the process responsible for the modification.

Comment: You can enable [audit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/audit-file-system) on this file, then attempts to access it would be logged to the security log. That includes the process information.

Comment: Or. you can use [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) instead. There is no user-mode API for applications to obtain the kind of information you are asking for. You have to write a device driver (that is what ProcMon uses internally) to get that kind of info from the kernel/filesystem.